# calculating the weekly hours worked and excluding the weekends using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like shown below and i would like to capture all 5 week days in every week whether the employee worked or not. If employee only worked 3 days, then i want to show the hours for the 3 days that he/she worked and assign 0 for the 2 missing days :

```
UID        DT         HOURS_WORKED
Mike      07/4/16          5
Mike      07/5/16          8
Mike      07/7/16          4
```

here is the desired results for this scenario

```
UID        DT         HOURS_WORKED
Mike      07/4/16          5
Mike      07/5/16          8
Mike      06/6/16          0
Mike      07/7/16          4
Mike      07/8/16          0
```

so i want to put 0 when they skipped work for that day. I don't want to show weekends.  Thanks for your help

```
select UID, DT, HOURS_WORKED from my table
```

Comment: do you have a master dates table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enhanced @vkp 's answer to make it more generic, ( if you are really picky we need to handle the edge cases where some days of the 1st week or last week can fall into different years )

Over here I have added the ability to change the first day of the week using the Datefirst  setting . more on Datefirst MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

```
/*  Setup Test Data
Drop Table #T1 

Create Table #T1 ( UID Varchar(10), Dt   Date, Hrs int )

insert into #T1 Values 
( 'Mike' , GetDate()   , 8 ) ,    -- Sat 07/23
( 'Mike' , GetDate()-1 , 8 ) ,
( 'Mike' , GetDate()-2 , 8 ) ,
( 'Mike' , GetDate()+3 , 8 )      -- Tue 07/26
( 'John' , GetDate()   , 8 ) ,    -- Sat 07/23
( 'John' , GetDate()-1 , 8 ) ,
( 'John' , GetDate()-2 , 8 ) ,
( 'John' , GetDate()+3 , 8 ) 


 insert into #T1 Values 
( 'Mike' , GetDate() - 206   , 8 ) ,   --- One Date for Last Year 12/30 to Test Edge Case

-- select * , DatePart( WEEK, Dt) from #T1
*/
```

-- Create a Helper TV Function To get Dates for a Given Week in a Year

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetDates
(
    @WK int ,
    @yr varchar(5) = ''
)


RETURNS 
    @Table_Var TABLE 
    (
        DD int, 
        Dt Date,
        Wk int
    )
AS

BEGIN

IF @yr = ''  SET @yr  = YEAR(Getdate()) -- If Year is Blank then Default to current year

Declare @LastDateOfYr Date = RTRIM(@YR)+'-12-31' -- Last Day of the year
Declare @LastDayOfYr Int = CAST(Datename(dy, @LastDateOfYr ) as int) -- No.of Days in the Year to Handle Leap Yrs

;WITH Dates as 
(
--  SELECT 0 as DD          ,  DATEADD(D, 0, @yr )        as Dt  , DatePart( WEEK,  DATEADD(D, 0 , @yr )) as Wk
    SELECT Datepart( DAYOFYEAR,DateAdd(D, (@WK-2)*7, @yr) ) as DD , DATEADD(D, (@WK-2)*7, @yr )  as Dt  ,  @WK-2 as Wk -- Initial values for the Recursive CTE.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Dates.DD+1 as DD ,  DATEADD(D, Dates.DD, @yr )         , DatePart( WEEK,DATEADD(D, Dates.DD, @yr )) from Dates where Dates.DD <= @LastDayOfYr
    AND Wk <= @WK + 1  -- Terminator for Recursion
) 

INSERT INTO @Table_Var 
SELECT 
        DD , 
        Dt ,
        Wk 
FROM Dates as A 
WHERE A.Wk = @WK
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 21)  -- At any point we dont use CTE For more than 3 Weeks (one week actually). If the CTE is changed by using the commented out Initializer inside the CTE Above then this number has to change accordingly

  RETURN 

END
GO
```

Query :

```
SET DATEFIRST 1  -- Make Monday as First Day of Week. The default is Sunday.

Select B.* , A.* , ISNULL(T.Hrs,0) Hours_Worked
FROM
        ( SELECT Distinct UID, 
                DatePart( WEEK, Dt) as WK , 
                DatePart( YEAR, Dt) as Yr 
          FROM #T1  
        ) A 
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetDates(A.WK, A.Yr ) B -- Helper Function Used to apply 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #T1 T ON B.Dt = T.Dt
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not work when you have multiple users and the numbers doses not up properly.

Comment: @moe I made a lot of changes ... take a look now

Comment: Thank you so much, what is this field DD in the output query?  I am trying to understand it now before i implement it.  thanks again

Comment: @moe Thats just the day of the year ... goes from 1 - 365 days from Jan 1 to Dec 31 and accounts for leap year as well.

Comment: @moe you are very welcome. Don't forget to test it for crazy scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

Construct a dates cte which will have all the dates in a week and perform an outer join on this table to show `0` when the employee doesn't work on a given weekday.

```
with x as (select cast('2016-07-01' as date) dt
           union all
           select dateadd(dd,1,dt) from x where dt < '2016-07-31')
select e.uid, t.dt, coalesce(e.hours_worked,0) hours_worked
from (select * from x where datepart(dw,dt) between 2 and 6) t
left join emp_table e on e.dt = t.dt
```

Comment: thanks vip, what is the parentheses at the end here? select dateadd(dd,1,dt) from x where dt < '2016-07-31')

Comment: that indicates the end of the `cte`.